# why google search console not show search query clicks correclty?

Tags: google-search-console, search-results

In google webmaster my site have 10 clicks 2 days ago but in search query not show what query was clicked by user!!!
I have 91 total clicks(in 3 month) and in queries only show 10 clicks for queris!
what is the problem?

Comment: I am afraid that Google is famous for this. It happens to all of us. It can be maddening! I suggest drinking a cup of coffee or a beer and going in the garden. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible reasons why these values differ. Without knowing your full situation, I recommending reading about [Data Discrepancies in the Performance Report](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en) for more information.

Comment: I have this problem in all of my websites.. my site is in 'Persian' .. can this cause the problem?